# LWC OSS help - styling issue

Tags: lightning-web-components, open-source

I'm having quite a bit of trouble with the changes made to LWC OSS. How do I get rid of these margins on the wrapper shown in the image? I can't seem to edit the styling of the html page itself. Only the individual components. If someone could enlighten me on this I'd appreciate it. How I used to remember this being done, you actually had access to this html document itself and could edit it (with the entry component going into div with id of 'main'). I also had to use JS to change the document.title. How can I access the html itself? Super confused with these changes.

[image]

Comment: So I was able to fix this by putting "document.body.style.margin = 0;" inside a renderedCallback. Had to do that as well to set the title of the page. 

Any better way of doing this?